# Save array to PHP file

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP file to store an array:

```
<?php
  $arr = array (
    "A" => "one",
    "B" => "two",
    "C" => "three"
  );
?>
```

I am using `require` to open the file, and each entry loads into a form. (`foreach` loop) I would like to save the `$_POST` variables back (overwriting) to the original file **in the same format**. I have no trouble making the form and sending back the variables. I just need a way to print the array back into the original file.

Example result:

```
<?php
  $arr = array (
    "A" => "new value",
    "B" => "other new value",
    "C" => "third new value"
  );
?>
```

I have been unable to use `print_r`, as the format returned is incorrect. How can I do this successfully? Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use `json_encode()` and `json_encode()` if you really want to save the array / object to a file?  Or `serialize()` and `unserialize()`.

Comment: I didn't got what you are trying here

Comment: `var_export()` comes closes to what you want, but there's no built-in PHP function that'd export a structure as executable PHP code. Use `serialize()` or `json_encode()` to store the data.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

You would use it like this

```
file_put_contents($filename, '<?php $arr = ' . var_export($arr, true) . ';');
```

### [DEMO](http://ideone.com/jS1xBd)

Answer (score 7):

You probably don't want to be re-writing your php code on the fly.

Two alternatives:

1. Use a database
2. [Serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array, then (over)write to file. When reading the file, you will just want to [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the value.
3. Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) as discussed in #2

Comment: I would like to be able to manually edit the file containing the array; the serialized array is not very readable when you have numerous entries.

Comment: json_encode / json_decode is definitely a workable alternative that will result in something a bit more readable/editable.

Comment: There are use cases where writing a php file with an array makes sense. E.g. writing of sensitive config files at app install.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually several ways to achieve that.

1. Open your file and write into it with file_put_contents() (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php)
2. write to the file your array encoded to string with JSON.encode (http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php)
3. read your file with file_get_contents (file_get_contents)
4. convert your string to an array with JSON.decode (http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php)